# Get child along with parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Consider the following two classess `School` and `Student`. School got collection of Students. also Student got associated with School which is not mapped

```
public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}
```

My modelbuilder looks like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<School>()
        .HasMany(obj => obj.students)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(obj => obj.SchoolId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<Student>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(e => e.School);
});
```

What worked -

```
var result = mydbcontext.Schools
                        .Include(d => d.students)
                        .Where(d => d.Id == 1)
                        .Select(x => new School
                        {
                            Id = x.Id,
                            students = x.students.Where(s => !s.Deleted).ToList()
                        })
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .ToList();
```

What is NOT working -

```
var school = mydbcontext.Students
                        .Include(x => x.School) //returning null
                        .Where(s => !s.Deleted)
                        .ToList();
```

When i tried the above code, I get all students which are not deleted, but I get `Empty` results for School

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I think Removing [NotMapped] will work

Comment: Thanks @PankajRawat, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks likely to be caused by your `[NotMapped]` attribute on the `Student` class `School` property. Using that attribute instructs EF not to create a corresponding column in the database for keying the `Student` record back to the `School` record, therefore EF will not be able to infer the `Student`->`School`relationship, only the `School`->`Students` relationship.

Comment: Note that removing that attribute will likely require you to run `dotnet ef database update` and you may need to repopulate your test data.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but no luck. removed `NotMapped`, added migration and updated database

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla Can you query `Students` the table in your database and confirm that it is now populating the `School` column with a valid foreign key to the `School` record? Also, reviewing your fluent API for your modelBuilder, you may want to add the Student-School relationship in `.WithOne()` on the school, like so: `.WithOne(s => s.School)`.

Comment: after adding `WithOne(s=>s.School`, it started working. unfortunately i get filtered students -> School -> all Students inside school. can i limit this to load only school and not load all students?

Comment: Sounds like you're referring to the lazy loading of related entities (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#lazy-loading). You should be able to prevent that by removing `virtual` from your declaration of the `School` property on your `Student` class.

Comment: once i remove `virtual`, i get this error on first query `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Navigation property 'School' on entity type 'Student' is not virtual. UseLazyLoadingProxies requires all entity types to be public, unsealed, have virtual navigation properties, and have a public or protected constructor.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208134/discussion-between-rbonestell-and-krishna-muppalla).